# How to show back-end message error, angular 10 only show statusText

Tags: asp.net-core, angular10

I return in my front-end(Angular10) a back-end(ASP.NET) message using angular alertService, but only show statusText equals NotFound, when should be "Usuário não encontrado.", in network a message is appears, but in alert not.

login.component.ts

```
onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;

    // reset alerts on submit
    this.alertService.clear();

    // stop here if form is invalid
    if (this.form.invalid) {
        return;
    }

    error: HttpErrorResponse ;
    
    this.loading = true;
    this.accountService.login(this.f.user_nome.value, this.f.user_accessKey.value)
        .pipe(first())
        .subscribe({
            next: () => {
                // get return url from query parameters or default to home page
                const returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';
                this.router.navigateByUrl(returnUrl);
            },
            error: error => {
                this.alertService.error(error);
                this.loading = false;
            }
        });
}
```

account.service.ts

```
login(user_nome, user_accessKey) {
    return this.http.post<User>(`${environment.apiUrl}/Conta/v1/login`, { user_nome,user_accessKey })
        .pipe(map(user => {
            // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
            localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
            this.userSubject.next(user);
            return user;
        }));
}
```

[Print Return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmk4Z.png)

[Message is comming in network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NACU.png)

[Console HttpErrorResponse return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXV38.png)